# "DRadialGaussian" is not available as built in function in Mathematica. How can I install package of it in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

I got an online video code of iris images where someone has used DRadialGaussian, which is not working in my Mathematica software. I need to install some extra package to run it. How can I obtain the code of DRadialGaussian package? I tried but not able to solve it up to now. I want it in Mathematica 13.0.

Comment: Has this got anything to do with CSS?